# Adding response for post in ModelViewset

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have to provide a DB status response (which tells if the serializer gets stored or not) after a POST request in ModelViewSet. Please help me perform that in the view.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Booking
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import BookingSerializer

class BookingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Booking.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookingSerializer
```

Comment: a 200 or 201 response indicates a successful post... not at all sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a 200 or 201 will do and django already handles this. If you want to override the response message

Here is a snippet

```
 from rest_framework.response import Response
 from rest_framework import status


 def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     ...
     return Response({'success': 'Data successfully submitted'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: It's not working for me. I get `Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field 'some_field' on serializer 'SomeSerializer'.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the dict instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'some_field'."`